# How to recover the datas in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Can recover the data in MySql after the updation?I update the field and by mistake i lost the correct data..

Comment: Maybe someone at serverfault.com can help, but unless you got a backup, your data is probably gone.

Answer (score 2):

No. This question has been asked multiple times already, the answer remains the same:

- If you're in a transaction, you can ROLLBACK.
- If you got backups or dumps, you can try to load and/or merge, and find the previous value.

Else: the value is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mate, can't be done, there is no versioning in mySQL tables.

Backups, backups, and backups are, sadly, the only solution.

In case somebody comes up with an ingenious method I don't know about, at any rate 1. Stop  the mySQL service and 2. if possible, stop doing anything on the machine the server runs on. But I doubt there is a solution.